# What is the syntax for variadic template array reference parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I don't know if what I have is a compiler bug or if I just don't know the syntax for what I'm trying to do. Imagine a function that takes 2 array references:

```
void takeArrays(const char (&str1)[4], const char (&str2)[4]) {
}
```

This compiles fine when called with:

```
takeArrays("foo", "bar");
```

Why would I want to do this? Because passing `const char*` loses the size information of the string literal, and that's important for what I'm doing.

What I really want to do, however, is pass a variadic number of array references. This is where things get slightly ugly (it gets worse). I naively tried this:

```
template<typename... Args>
void takeArrays(const char (&Args... strs)[4]) {
}
```

And got `"error: variable or field ‘takeArrays’ declared void"` and `"error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’"` (gcc 4.6). So I tried this:

```
template<typename... Args>
void takeArrays(const char (&(Args... strs))[4]) {
}
```

And got `"no matching function for call to ‘takeArrays(const char [4], const char [4])’"` and `"candidate is template<class ... Args> void takeArrays(const char (& (*)(Args ...))[4])"`. Which is unreadable but seems close to what I want. I've tried many variations and can't seem to get it to compile.

Assuming there's a proper way to write the above, what I really want to do is call:

```
takeArrays("foo", "foobar", "longerstring");
```

And get a variadic list of arrays of different sizes, i.e. the call above should be expanded by the compiler to:

```
void takeArrays(const char (&str1)[4], const char (&str2)[7],
                const char (&str3)[13]);
```

Which was the first think I tried doing, and my attempt was something like:

```
template<size_t... Sizes>
void takeArrays(const char (&strs)[Sizes]...);
```

Needless to say all I got was error messages. I'm aware that what I'm trying to do is a bit crazy but I really want to know if it's possible, and if so, what the appropriate syntax is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax for variadic arrays of the same element type is:

```
template<size_t... Sizes>
void takeArrays(const char (&...args)[Sizes]);
```

This is similar to the general variadic const reference syntax:

```
template<typename... Args>
void takeArrays(const Args &...args);
```

An easy way to remember is that the ellipsis goes immediately before the parameter name.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks! I'll remember the ellipsis before parameter name trick. Out of curiosity, how would I write the original parameters of the same size? I tried `template<typename...Args> void takeArrays(cont char Args (&... args([4])` and `const char (Args &... args)[4]` and those don't work.

Comment: @ÁtilaNeves That can't be made to work for the same reason that you can't write a variadic function template taking multiple `int`s: `template</* what to put here?? */> void foo(int... i /* doesn't work: no pack to expand here */);`. The usual workaround would be to allow arrays of the same size with different element type, i.e. `template<typename... T, std::size_t Size> void foo(T (&... args)[Size]);`. You can then optionally add a `static_assert` to enforce that all `T` be `const char`.